# Digital Identity with signing

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, signature

Is there a way to sign some data right out from a smart contract? 
Let's say I want to create a smart contract, that will represent my Digital Identity and I want it to have sign() method. Maybe something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
```

contract DID {

```
address owner;

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function sign(string _msgToBeSigned) public onlyOwner returns (bytes32) {
    // here to sign the message
    // and here to return the signed message
}

function verify(bytes32 _signedMessage) public view returns (bool) {
    // here to verify if owner == ecrecover(..., v, r, s)
    // here to return true or false
}
```

}

So the question is:
**Is it possible to perform these two actions from within a smart contract without use of client code like `web3.eth.sign()`?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ecrecover` works roughly as you'd expect](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions), but `sign` doesn't really make sense. All data on the blockchain is public, so a contract can't keep any sort of private key secret.

If you could elaborate on what you're trying to do (e.g. "I want to prove X to Y."), people might be able to suggest other ideas.